# Can a value in a variable and a string with backslashes be combined in ansible?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have an ansible playbook in which one variable I am passing from the command. I am trying to append a windows folder path to it. One way I am able to find out is to add the path to another variable and then join the two variable. I would like to know if it is possible to avoid the variable and put the path like this:
"{{ variable2 }} \build\dist\package\ui.msi"

variable1 has value "d:\install"
var_build_file_name is entered by the user
variable2 is formed by combining variable1 and var_build_number.

This is the actual content in the playbook which works:

```
  vars:
    installerFolder: "{{ UploadFolder }}{{ var_build_file_name | regex_replace('(\\.zip)','\') }}"
    packagePath: '\build\dist\package\UI.msi'

  - name: Install new version.
    debug:
      msg: "{{ installerFolder }}{{ packagePath }}"
```

And this is the playbook command:

```
ansible-playbook Install.yml -i ../inventory/hosts.ini --extra-vars "target=servername var_build_file_name=16.3.0.zip UploadFolder=D:\Install\\"
```

The output I am getting is:

"msg": "D:\\Install\\16.3.0\\build\\dist\\package\\UI.msi"

In the above output, how come two backslashes are showing instead of one?

Is it possible to do

```
msg: "{{ installerFolder }} '\build\dist\package\UI.msi' "
```

I have tried many combinations but the backslashes are not getting properly escaped for above. If it is not possible then can someone enlighten on the reason.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"msg": "D:\\Install\\16.3.0\\build\\dist\\package\\UI.msi"
```

It is the output of debug module, which is a JSON string, so every `\` is escaped.
The actual value of the msg here is `D:\Install\16.3.0\build\dist\package\UI.msi`, as you expect it.

And you can definitely use this syntax: `msg: '{{ installerFolder }}\build\dist\package\UI.msi'`

Comment: This does not work for me. Ansible gives me error with pointer under the \ before dist word.

The offending line appears to be: path: "{{ installerFolder }}\build\dist\package\TR.OA.UI\TR.OA.UI.msi"

Comment: @Aseem Note, that I use single quotes for sake of simplicity. If you use double quotes, you should escape all special characters (nesting single quotes doesn't work, as in your code): `msg: "{{ installerFolder }}\\build\\dist\\package\\UI.msi"`