# Ansible Escaping in Shell Module

Tags: ansible

I was trying to configure an application to connect to ldap and noticed it was failing authentication, so I thought I would check the two commands that get executed to set this up to see what the shell command that ansible executes looks like. 
So I disabled the `mqsichangeproperties` and `mqsisetdbparms` commands on the server and created the below little test playbook to see what the command string looks like... I run the playbook expecting an error of `mqsisetdbparms: command not found`
but this would allow me to see `cmd` and `_raw_params` keys when running with verbose output.

I noticed that the command for the first task is in the form that I expect:

`"cmd": "mqsichangeproperties QM -b webadmin -o server -n ldapAuthenticationUri –v \"ldap://abc.company.com:389/OU=Users,OU=City,OU=Country,DC=company,DC=com\""`

However, the command for the second task contains additional blackslashes, resulting in the incorrect username and password being set for the application...

**Incorrect command form:**

`"cmd": "mqsisetdbparms QM -n ldap::company.com -u \"DOMAIN\\username\" -p \"pwd@pwd\""`

**Expected command form:**

`"cmd": "mqsisetdbparms QM -n ldap::company.com -u "DOMAIN\username" -p "pwd@pwd""`

I feel as if have tried all possible options such as

- using double quotes for the variables
- escaping in the variables
- combination of single and double quotes with the variables and the shell command string
- Escaping the backslash in the `ldap_usr` variable

The test playbook I am using is below...

```
---
# file: test.yml
# desc: Test playbook
#
- hosts: target
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    ldap_server: "ldap://abc.company.com"
    ldap_port: 389
    ldap_baseDN: "OU=Users,OU=City,OU=Country,DC=company,DC=com"
    ldap_usr: 'DOMAIN\username'
    ldap_pwd: 'pwd@pwd'
    ldap_auth_uri: "\"{{ldap_server}}:{{ldap_port}}/{{ldap_baseDN}}\""
  tasks:
#    - name: test setting URI
#      shell: "mqsichangeproperties QM -b webadmin -o server -n ldapAuthenticationUri -v {{ldap_auth_uri}}"
    - name: test setting user
      shell: "mqsisetdbparms QM -n ldap::company.com -u \"{{ldap_usr}}\" -p \"{{ldap_pwd}}\""
```

Using Ansible Version **2.2.0.0**

Comment: Your command is OK. You see escaped output in the ansible output. http://stackoverflow.com/a/38957727/2795592

Comment: Thanks for that! Yup my problem was using the wrong mechanism to diagnose the original problem :)   I was never aware about the Ansible log printing _escaped_ JSON, I assumed it was raw for the values .. I will now amend my full script and test that the application can connect to the ldap server but looks to be good to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like the following should work:

```
ldap_usr: 'DOMAIN\\username'
```

```
shell: mqsisetdbparms QM -n ldap::company.com -u \"{{ldap_usr}}\" -p \"{{ldap_pwd}}\"
```

---

When I echo the resulting string to a file with:

```
shell: echo mqsisetdbparms QM -n ldap::company.com -u \"{{ldap_usr}}\" -p \"{{ldap_pwd}}\" > ./check.txt
```

or

```
shell: printf "mqsisetdbparms QM -n ldap::company.com -u \"{{ldap_usr}}\" -p \"{{ldap_pwd}}\"" > ./check.txt
```

I get:

```
mqsisetdbparms QM -n ldap::company.com -u "DOMAIN\username" -p "pwd@pwd"
```

which is what you requested.

---

By the way, you shouldn't rely on the Ansible log to determine what is the real command, as it prints escaped JSON.

Comment: Thanks! That worked!    I had thought about writing the string to a file but for some brain fade reason I never did... I was never aware about the Ansible log printing _escaped_ JSON, I assumed it was raw for the values .. I will now amend my full script and test that the application can connect to the ldap server but looks to be good to me!